# Where is my wasteland apartment?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

Rumor has it, I have real estate in the desert. Where though? I've looked at where the map points me, but couldn't find anything...

[image]

Comment: This is most likely an incomplete feature that is still partially in game. During the first part of the game before completing the Aldecados quest line up to and including their camp move, there is a "house" marked on the map which is actually somebody else's tent. You can find this location in the Aldecado camp and you'll be able to walk in but will find other people already there and won't be able to interact with anything inside the tent.

After completing the Aldecados quest line up to the camp move, you will actually have a usable tent with a stash in it at the new camp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just played along the Aldocado's storyline a little further and the camp moved. In the new camp, I do have my own tent with stash. New location is here:

[image]

Comment: You get these icons with every NPC romance too, but it doesn't actually work as a home it seems. Though the NPC you are romancing may leave items as gift for you at that spot.